# Prestashop credit card paiement module

Tags: prestashop

I'm using prestashop 1.7 and have installed the stripe free official stripe component.
unfortunately the module doesn't display correctly...and the support take a loooot of time to manage my trouble ..i need to publish . my shop tomorrow and need a credit card module .

I've seen Payplug and SystemPay
https://systempay.cyberpluspaiement.com/html/contributions.html
https://addons.prestashop.com/fr/paiement-carte-wallet/8795-payplug-paiement-en-ligne-simple-et-securise-.html

...living inn Switzerland.. do you have any advises for me ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: use SystemPay :)

Comment: thx, i've got trouble with configuration, everything working now !!!!